# Retrieve only the queried matched element in an object array in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

my MongoDB Structure is

```
{
    "_id": "QR00000017",
    "packagingTypeID": "PTI00010",
    "packages": [{
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_9",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_9"
    }, {
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_10",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_10"
    }, {
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_11",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_11"
    }, {
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_12",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_12"
    }, {
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_13",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_13"
    }, {
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_14",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_14"
    }, {
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_15",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_15"
    }]
  
}
```

Now i input multiple packageIDs as input in array and wanted to retrieve only those that matches back from the mongodb example ["QR00000017_13","QR00000017_14"] like the output given below

```
{
        "_id": "QR00000017",
        "packagingTypeID": "PTI00010",
        "packages": [{
            "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_13",
            "packageID": "QR00000017_13"
        }, {
            "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_14",
            "packageID": "QR00000017_14"
        }]
      
    }
```

My Code is

```
packages_in_str=["QR00000017_13","QR00000017_14"];
Criteria usernameCriteria = Criteria.where("packages.packageID").in(packages_in_str); query.fields().include("packages.$");
```

The output i am getting is

```
{
"_id": "QR00000017",
    "packagingTypeID": "PTI00010",
    "packages": [{
        "packageQRCode": "QR00000017_HR00000137_PTI00010_13",
        "packageID": "QR00000017_13"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#---projection-):

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  to return the first element that matches the query condition on the array

If you want to return all matches, you will need to use aggregation with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#-filter--aggregation-)